# How to draw a view, which should be floating over the all activity in the same app?

Tags: android, overlay

I want a view should be floating over the activity of app, not over the other app.

I'm using a image view in activity c.Activity c is on top of two activity a,b. I'm having a button to minimise the Activity in activity c. Once I minimised, the imageview should be float on the Activity b.Even I closed the activity b, it should be overlay on activity a. How to achieve this?

Comment: Can you add an image so it's quicker to grasp?

Comment: you can't have the same button floating across different activities, but you can clone the button on each activity and show it

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the workflow:
Create another activity d. Lets call FloatActivity.

1st: change the theme of the activity from manifiest.

```
<activity
    android:name=".FloatActivity"
    android:label="Float Button"
    <!-- Use Translucent theme to get transparent activity background 
     and NoTitleBar to avoid super old style title bar ;) -->
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
</activity>
```

2nd: Now edit the .xml of the FloatActivity

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/popButton"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#000"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

3rd: Now code for java

```
public class FloatActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener{

    private ImageButton floatButton;

    private int previousFingerPosition = 0;
    private int baseLayoutPosition = 0;
    private int defaultViewHeight;

    private boolean isClosing = false;
    private boolean isScrollingUp = false;
    private boolean isScrollingDown = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_popup);
        floatButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.popButton);
        floatButton.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }


    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

        // Get finger position on screen
        final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();

        // Switch on motion event type
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // save default base layout height
                defaultViewHeight = baseLayout.getHeight();

                // Init finger and view position
                previousFingerPosition = Y;
                baseLayoutPosition = (int) baseLayout.getY();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // If user was doing a scroll up
                if(isScrollingUp){
                    // Reset baselayout position
                    baseLayout.setY(0);
                    // We are not in scrolling up mode anymore
                    isScrollingUp = false;
                }

                // If user was doing a scroll down
                if(isScrollingDown){
                    // Reset baselayout position
                    baseLayout.setY(0);
                    // Reset base layout size
                    baseLayout.getLayoutParams().height = defaultViewHeight;
                    baseLayout.requestLayout();
                    // We are not in scrolling down mode anymore
                    isScrollingDown = false;
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if(!isClosing){
                    int currentYPosition = (int) baseLayout.getY();

                    // If we scroll up
                    if(previousFingerPosition >Y){
                        // First time android rise an event for "up" move
                        if(!isScrollingUp){
                            isScrollingUp = true;
                        }

                    // Has user scroll down before -> view is smaller than it's default size -> resize it instead of change it position
                    if(baseLayout.getHeight()<defaultViewHeight){
                        baseLayout.getLayoutParams().height = baseLayout.getHeight() - (Y - previousFingerPosition);
                        baseLayout.requestLayout();
                    }
                    else {
                        // Has user scroll enough to "auto close" popup ?
                        if ((baseLayoutPosition - currentYPosition) > defaultViewHeight / 4) {
                            closeUpAndDismissDialog(currentYPosition);
                            return true;
                        }

                        //
                    }
                    baseLayout.setY(baseLayout.getY() + (Y - previousFingerPosition));

                }
                // If we scroll down
                else{

                    // First time android rise an event for "down" move
                    if(!isScrollingDown){
                        isScrollingDown = true;
                    }

                    // Has user scroll enough to "auto close" popup ?
                    if (Math.abs(baseLayoutPosition - currentYPosition) > defaultViewHeight / 2)
                    {
                        closeDownAndDismissDialog(currentYPosition);
                        return true;
                    }

                    // Change base layout size and position (must change position because view anchor is top left corner)
                    baseLayout.setY(baseLayout.getY() + (Y - previousFingerPosition));
                    baseLayout.getLayoutParams().height = baseLayout.getHeight() - (Y - previousFingerPosition);
                    baseLayout.requestLayout();
                }

                // Update position
                previousFingerPosition = Y;
            }
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now, before minimizing your activity just start the activity d(FloatActivity).

Comment: I need something like facebook chat head head. But it should be overlay in my app activities, not others..